ImportError: cannot import name 'check_pandas_support' from 'sklearn.utils'
These are the versions of packages I have:
Python dependencies:
sklearn: 1.5.0
pip: 24.0
setuptools: 70.0.0
numpy: 1.23.1
scipy: 1.13.1
Cython: None
pandas: 2.2.2
matplotlib: 3.8.2
joblib: 1.4.2
threadpoolctl: 3.5.0
I've tried updating versions. I'm running this from a jupyter notebook. Anyone know how to fix this?
I get this error when I try:
from skopt import gp_minimize

I fixed this by downgrading from 1.5.0 to 1.3.2
